# Leaflet markers move around when zooming

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

```js
for (var i = 0; i < markers.value.length; i++) {
    new L.marker([markers.value[i].location.lat, markers.value[i].location.lon])
      .addTo(markersLayer.value)
      .bindTooltip(L.tooltip({ sticky: true, content: 'god' }));
  }
```

it's a map that displays a group of markers. Now, the first time you load it with a layer there are no issues, the problem is whenever I change the markers (clearing all of them with `markersLayer.value.clearLayers()` and running back again the loop with the new array), and also it would only happen with tooltips when commenting `.bindTooltip(L.tooltip({ sticky: true, content: 'god' }));` i cannot reproduce it. Also if I don't clear the layer you can see the first array of markers stuck to the map but the new ones just won't work.

[showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1GTI.gif)

I tried almost everything and it has some randomness, but what I found to be almost 90% sure the breaking component, is the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Vue reactivity was bugging it, removing map and the layers from a ref() fixed the issue.